# Rate of change in distance

Tags: calculus, differential

I don't know how to start with this problem. Please help me figure it out.

here it is :)

Navy Seal Ship A moves along towards east direction at the constant rate of 'a' meter/sec^2 while Navy Seal Ship B moves toward north at constant rate of 'b' meter/sec^2. Determine how fast the distance between them is changing when Ship A is at the coordinates of (x,0) and ship B is at the coordinates of (y,0).

Answer (score 1):

First remember these few rules:

s= distance ;
d(s)/dt is the speed of the object;
and
second differential of distance is accelaration.

From my understanding, u firstly need to double integrate the accelaration (given in ur question) of each object at those points given to find the distance from the origin and then from there can u use Pythagorus theorem.

Comment: i got it sir. thank you

Comment: a vote up would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they start at $(0,0)$, the distance between them is given by Pythagoras' theorem :
$$
f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
So by the chain rule
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}
$$
$$
= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}a + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}b
$$

Comment: sir... would it be possible if i use the pythagorean theorem that goes this way? c^2 = a^2 + b^2 ?

Comment: @henna : That is exactly what I have used here! $c$ is denoted by $f(x,y)$ since it is a function (it changes as the ships move)

Comment: is there any more possible refined solution for that sir? what symbol is that before f/x and f/y?